# Generate non-homogeneous Poisson process in R

Tags: r, poisson

I am attempting to use a thinning algorithm (described below) to generate the first 10 time units of a non-homogeneous Poisson process in R. The intensity function λ(t) = 3 + 4/(t+1)

**Thinning algorithm:**

Step 1: t = 0, I = 0.

step 2: Generate a random number U.

step 3: t = t − 1/λ (log U). If t > T , stop.

step 4: Generate a random number U.

step 5: If U <= λ(t)/λ, set I = I + 1, S(I) = t.

step 6: Go to Step 2

t = time

I = number of events that have occurred by time t.

S(I) = the most recent event time

The final value of I represents the number of events at time T, and S(1), . . . , S(I) are the
event times.

I have some example code from a lecture that I'm trying to use to figure this out, but I have not come very far. Any ideas on what I can try to do? (I'm a noob to coding, so if you have any ideas keep that in mind when explaining)

```
PoissonTime<-function(s,lambdat,lambda)
 {
  t<-s
  repeat{
    U<-runif(2)
    t<-t-log(U[1])/lambda
    if (U[2]<=lambdat/lambda)
    {Ts=t;break;}
  }
  return(Ts)
}

#### An intensity function for Poisson process

lambdat<-function(t,TT)
{
  rho<-t/TT
  lambdat<- 3 + (4/(t+1))
  return(lambdat)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the theoretical details of the thinning algorithm (maybe, e.g., `Lewis & Shedler, Simulation of Non-Homogeneous Poisson Processes by Thinning, 1978`),  but   I tried to to the coding following your pseudo codes  as follows:

```r
nhpp_thin = function(lambdat, lambda=7, T=10)
{
  t = 0; I = 0; S = 0
  U1 = runif(1); t = t - log(U1)/lambda  
  while(t < T){
    U2 = runif(1)
    if( U2 <= lambdat(t)/lambda ){
      I  =  I + 1; S[I] = t
    }
    U1 = runif(1); t = t - log(U1)/lambda  
  }
  list(I = I, S = S)
}
lambdat =  function(t) 3 + 4/(t+1)
set.seed(0); nhpp_thin(lambdat) #seed for repeatability
## $I
## [1] 38
## 
## $S
##  [1] 0.01557672 0.15679507 0.17054965 0.24504376 0.64276863 0.89049904
##  [7] 1.12803173 1.38549445 1.68192454 1.81787059 2.10917107 2.18224957
## [13] 3.07166333 3.10545441 3.26357860 3.28492396 3.48597037 3.81567576
## [19] 4.21302451 4.56390493 4.60192887 4.62095233 4.64595517 4.80271065
## [25] 4.95926503 5.00768714 5.69699803 5.97453865 6.43024234 6.77806501
## [31] 6.99989776 7.22319044 7.34326883 8.28728247 8.45130080 9.03904437
## [37] 9.47920323 9.87700029
```

Comment: To check `nhpp_thin`, you may refer to other materials such as [276454](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276454/how-to-simulate-poisson-arrival-times-if-the-rate-varies-with-time)